# How to fill dataframe Nan values with empty list [] of 4 elements in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

This is my dataframe:

```
          date                          ids
0     2011-04-23  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
1     2011-04-24  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
2     2011-04-25  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
3     2011-04-26  NaN
4     2011-04-27  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
5     2011-04-28  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
```

I want to replace `Nan` with [[],[],[],[]]. How to do that?

```
df['ids'].fillna("").apply(list)
```

Is working well for a 1 element list, but how can we use it with 4 element list?

Comment: Is it a string or `np.nan`?

Comment: it is a np.nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `fillna` with lists, but you can create a Series containing your list repeated for the length of the dataframe, and assign that to the `b` where `b` is NaN:

```py
df.loc[df['b'].isna(), 'b'] = pd.Series([ [[]]*4 ] * len(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```py
df['ids'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda x: [[],[],[],[]] if x!=x else x)
```

This uses the feature that `np.nan` is not equal with itself.

Comment: Cool to take advantage of that property of NaN. However, `apply` is necessarily going to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.apply()` checking if the value is `np.nan` or not. If yes, then fill the nested list otherwise the normal value.

Try this:

```
df['ids'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda d: d if d is not np.nan else [[],[],[],[]])
```